# Find the $L^2 (-\pi,\pi)$-norm

Tags: integration, hilbert-spaces

Find the $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$-norm of $1, sin(x), cos(x)$

I am just wondering if I am on the right track:

$||1-cos(x)-sin(x)||_2= \bigg(\displaystyle\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (1-cos(x)-sin(x))^2 dx\bigg)^{\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}}$

$(1-cos(x)-sin(x))^2 = sin^2(x)+2cos(x)sin(x)-2sin(x)+cos^2(x)-2cos(x)+1$

$\bigg(\displaystyle\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (1-cos(x)-sin(x))^2 dx\bigg)^{\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}} = \bigg(\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} sin^2x dx+2\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} cos(x)sin(x)dx - 2\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} sin(x)dx + \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} cos^2(x)dx - 2\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} cos(x)dx + \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} dx \bigg)^{\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: Your first line is mistyped.

Comment: It looks like you're answering the question "Find the $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$ norm of $1-\cos(x)-\sin(x)$", but it appears that you're asked to find the norms of $1$, $\cos(x)$, and $\sin(x)$ separately.

Comment: @Aweygan oh well if that is the case, are these correct: $||1||_2 = \sqrt{2\pi}, ||sinx||_2 = \sqrt{\pi} = ||cosx||_2$?

Comment: That looks right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computation is going fine. Now some advice.

First, you usually want to work without the square roots; you calculate the norm squared, and then take the square root at the end.

Also, you can save quite a bit of effort if you already know that $1,\sin x,\cos x$ are mutually orthogonal on $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$. So you just have, for pairwise orthogonal vectors $x,y,z$, that $$ \|x+y+y\|^2=\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2+\|z\|^2.$$ Then 
\begin{align}
\|1-\sin x-\cos x\|^2=\|1\|^2+\|\sin x\|^2+\|\cos x\|^2=2\pi+2\|\sin x\|^2. 
\end{align}
Then the only computation one needs is 
$$
\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin ^2 x\, dx=\pi.
$$
Thus 
$$
\|1-\sin x-\cos x\|=\sqrt{4\pi}=2\sqrt\pi. 
$$